# get the id of selected item in select option and send it to an URL

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in sending the id of selected item from a select input to my rest service,I have two controllers,the first display all the classes:

```
.controller("classNameCtrl", ["$scope", "$http",function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'URL/Classes'})

       .success(function (data) {
           $scope.posts = data; // response data  
           $scope.countSelected = $scope.posts[0].Id;    
           console.log('Selected count ID: ' + $scope.countSelected);
           console.log("success");
        })

        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("data error ...");
                            });

        $scope.onchange = function(id) {
        console.log("id:"+$scope.countSelected);
           } }])
```

and the controller in which I get the ID of selected item from the select input:

```
.controller("etudajoutCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.listetud = function () {

          $http({method: 'POST',
          url:'URL/Students/ajout' ,
          data:'{"FirstName":"tomy","ClassId": "'+$scope.countSelected+'"}'})
          .success(function (data) {
            console.log("success");
             }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data error ...");
             });}
    }])
```

this is my HTML code:

```
    <div ng-controller="classNameCtrl">
        <select>
            <option ng-model="countSelected" ng-change="onchange(posts[countSelected-1])" ng-repeat="post in posts" >{{post.Libel}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</section>
```

this is the result I get always when I load the page and when I choose other items for the select input:

```
Selected count ID: 1
app.js:2335 success
```

thanks  alot for help

Comment: You should use `ng-model` on the `select` not the `option `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should use the `ng-model` for the entire select. You can't use the `ng-model` directive multiple times in the `<option>` because it won't bind properly.

Also, set the value property to a number so that `countselected` will be a number.

The best way to use a number is to iterate with the `$index`

```
<div ng-controller="classNameCtrl">
    <select ng-model="countSelected" ng-change="onchange(posts[countSelected-1])">
        <option ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index" value="{{$index}}" >{{post.Libel}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: thanks cjds for your  reply,but this is what I get when I apply your code and select items from the input :                                                             Selected count ID: 1
success
id:$index

Comment: @hanali my mistake. I forgot to add a angular binding tag to the option

Comment: @hanali  I've noticed you sometimes don't do that in your profile and it serves as a moral boost and gives us points. So, its usually appreciated if you comment why you don't accept any answers.

Comment: thanks cdjs it works now,but how can I send the $index value to the URL of the etudajoutCtrl controller?

Comment: if I use                                                                           .controller("etudajoutCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.listetud = function () {

          $http({method: 'POST',
          url:'URL/Students/ajout' ,
          data:'{"FirstName":"tomy","ClassId": "'+$scope.countSelected+'"}'})
          ............}
    }])   I get undifined value for $scope.countSelected !!

Comment: @hanali . It's a normal angular tag inside the `option value`. Just change it to whatever you need, `{{...}}`.

Answer (score 1):

While I think it is a brilliant way to use $index as the value, I recommend using the built in `ng-options` in this case.

Assuming data structure:

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope) {
  $scope.posts = [{
    Id: 1,
    Libel: 'one'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Libel: 'two'
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Libel: 'three'
  }]
  
  // $scope.countSelected = 2; // add this if you need to pre-select
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <select ng-model="countSelected" ng-options="post.Id as post.Libel for post in posts" ng-change="onchange(countSelected)"></select>
</div>
```